# JQuery fetch data from Mysql

Tags: php, jquery

I have succesfully recetrive data from mysql
the code is as follows

```
alert(data);
$.each(data, function(index, data) {
                        alert(index);
                        alert(data);
                    });
```

I want to see data.comments.
the message in alert(data) is

[{"visible":"0","comments":"fiat","post_id":"103007636522630"},{"visible":"0","comments":"volvo","post_id":"103007636522630"}]

however, in the each function, it shows each character, for example, index=1, data=[, index=2, data={, index=3, data=">

Do anyone know why this happens, I would like to fetch the whole row instead of each character

PHP code

```
$data2= $_POST['string'];

$data3= explode(",", $data2);

$data = array();

foreach ($data3 as &$value) {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM afb_comments where post_id='".$value."'";  
   $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $row_data = array(
       'visible' => $row[0], 
       'comments' => $row[1],
       'post_id' => $row[2]
    );
   array_push($data, $row_data);
  }
  }
 echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: are you setting `dataType:'json` in ajax request? Should move away from `mysql_` methods and use PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse your JSON response.

This can be done automatically if you use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or if you set the `dataType` option in your AJAX call like `dataType:'json'`

Or if you want to do it manually:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(data, function(index, data) {
    alert(index);
    alert(data);
});
```